# Making a user input only accept int but store in String

Tags: java, string, int

Got my program done and this is the only piece I cant figure out I have to check to see if the user entered `String userPhone` is an integer

```
System.out.println("Please enter your phone number (10-dights only)");
        String userNumber=sc.nextLine();

        while(true) {
            if (userNumber.length()==10) {
                order01.cust1.setPhoneNumber(userNumber);
                break;
            }
            else if (userNumber.length()!=10) {
                System.out.println("Invalid phone number, Enter a valid one");
            }
            userNumber=sc.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation?noredirect=1&lq=1 in case you are specifically looking to match phone number patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check matching for digits. matches() method of string take regular expression. Here \d* represent all characters should be digits only. and before that we are checking for length also.

```
 while(true) {
        if (userNumber.length()==10 && userNumber.matches("\\d*")) {
            System.out.println(userNumber);
            break;
        }
        else if (userNumber.length()!=10 || !userNumber.matches("\\d*")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid phone number, Enter a valid one");
        }
        userNumber=sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: @chris use this one

Comment: Is this useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *regular expression* to validate that the `String` contains exactly ten digits that would be `\d{10}` - and you don't need an `else` after your `break`. Like,

```
while(true) {
     if (userNumber.matches("\\d{10}")) {
         order01.cust1.setPhoneNumber(userNumber);
         break;
     }
     System.out.println("Invalid phone number, Enter a valid one");
     userNumber=sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: but this solution only tests the length of userNumber it doesn't validate that the String contains only integers so it passes "abcdefghiJ" as a valid number

Comment: @chriscrosby No. `\\d{10}` will only match 10 digits. `0-9`.

Comment: I was testing the wrong method this solution worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most primitive would be to loop through the input string(since your string is only 10 units long) and check if character at each index is a digit using `Character.isDigit`

Comment: try using string methods which take regular expression .

Answer (score 0):

Please refer for the  link for more information and original credits to this link : [Original Code](http://jdevelopment.nl/efficient-determine-string-number/)

Try the below method:

```
       public static boolean isNumber(String string) {
        try {
            Long.parseLong(string);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
```

in your code :

```
if (isNumber(userPhone)) {
         order01.cust1.setPhoneNumber(userNumber);
         break;
     }
```

Comment: This also work fine but for validation it is more suitable to use regular expression.

Comment: Yes it is better to use regular expression, I tried my best to answer !!